# dracut warning: /dev/mapper/foobar does not exists

Tags: partition, grub, uefi, luks, void-linux

I'm trying to install Void Linux with LUKS encryption on the root partition, currently, my `/etc/fstab` file looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime 0 2
/dev/sda2 swap swap rw,noatime,discard 0 2
/dev/mapper/foobar / ext4 rw,relatime 0 1
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid,nodev 0 2
```

I also appended these lines to my `/etc/default/grub` config file:

```
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=cryptdevice=UUID=<foobar_uuid>:foobar root=/dev/mapper/foobar
```

My `crypttab` file:

```
foobar /dev/sda3 /boot/volume.key luks
```

And last but not least `/etc/dracut.conf.d/10-crypt.conf`:

```
install_items+=" /boot/volume.key /etc/crypttab "
```

> I'm fetching `foobar` partition UUID through `blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sda3`

Whenever i pass the GRUB menu selection screen, some logs start appearing, and after a few seconds, the boot process is interrupted with the message on the title, unable to proceed any further

Comment: https://docs.voidlinux.org/installation/guides/fde.html the official guide suggests that you should have different contents in `/etc/default/grub` . Try to follow this and if possible start over.

Comment: @Alex iirc, the official guide uses LVM, right? does it still applies to this case as well where i only want to have a single luks encrypted root partition?

Comment: can you post the contents of /etc/crypttab in the initial answer and /etc/dracut.conf.d/10-crypt.conf